# Passing my own ConnectionString in Castle Active Record

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord

How can I inject my own ConnectionString if using Castle Active Record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the answer for this from http://www.darkside.co.za/archive/2008/01/21/castle-activerecord-connecting-to-multiple-databases.aspx

```
IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TestB;Integrated Security=SSPI");
connection.Open();
using (new DifferentDatabaseScope(connection))
{
    TestTableDatabaseA test3 = TestTableDatabaseA.Find(1);
    Console.WriteLine(test3.Title);
}
```